# Using ViewGroup in custom row for Listview causing casting issue

Tags: android, xml, android-viewgroup

I have a ListFragment with custom row as follows.

Fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="top|center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorAppBackground">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Custom_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/rootCategory_TextView"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/rootCategoryText"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/subCategory_RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting following error:

```
ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
.....
android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

It works fine if i remove LinearLayout ViewGroup from Custom_row.xml and just directly add textView but but my custom row needs more than one view and I have tired using all types of ViewGroups but they all give the above cast error

Comment: post your adapter code for custom view

Comment: Also, trying to use a `RecyclerView` in a `ListView` item layout is probably not going to work out well.

Comment: @AbishekPatel Sorry for the late reply, being the first time user I had not implemented the Adapter yet since I thought that will not cause a problem. However, after implementing Adapter the problem still persists.

Comment: @MikeM. So what can be the best alternative for nested list inside list.